# Merge Request: Merge [marvel-cinematic-universe] & [marvel] -> [marvel-universe]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

I've been looking at these two tags, trying to come up with some reasons as to why we have both of them.

I started by looking at the descriptions:

> - [marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel)  (No Description)
> - [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) Refers to the shared fictional movie universe that is the setting of superhero films independently produced by Marvel Studios.

Ok, so questions about the cinematic universe created by marvel are on topic, we *are* a Movies and TV site. **Answers** can reference other media types, however a **question** about comic-book Hulk would considered off-topic.

We could just merge [marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) into [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) (or vice-versa, but see the note below), **However**, as I've already mentioned, we are a Movies and TV site, i.e. *the 'cinematic' part of the tag is redundant.*

I propose that the tag should be [marvel-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-universe), with the description:

> A fictional universe populated with superheroes (and villains), which is the setting of many cinematic films produced by Marvel Studios. Questions should use this tag when asking about interactions that affect the overall universe, not sequences in specific movies.

What do you think?

<sub>**Note**:
I'm also averse to having a blanket 'marvel' tag. I think it would get misused, added to questions that are about a particular movie, or a sequence which has no bearing on the overarching universe (like the wiki description above implies).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the below mentioned question

[Why does Stan Lee play random extras in Marvel films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/why-does-stan-lee-play-random-extras-in-marvel-films)

It has [stan-lee](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stan-lee) and [marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) tag's.
It surely dereve both the tag and [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag doesn't suits here because it's about all marvel superhero movies not only about the new made [Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe).

[marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag have its own important in the avenger related films. But Spider-man and x-men films doesn't belongs to Marvel Cinematic Universe, so merging 
[marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) tag under [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe)  is completely wrong. And it's reverse is also looks wrong because [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag  has his own different importance.

There are 5 question tagged under [marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) ,out of which only one have [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag. Other three doesn't belongs to Marvel Cinematic Universe and the remaining one belong's more to [marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) then [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe).

Similarly [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag have 5 questions which are belongs to Marvel Cinematic Universe directly.

So, i think they are good as separated.

Comment: Now that you mention it, Every question currently under [marvel] doesn't need that tag - It is completely superfluous. Of the 5 questions tagged, 3 of them are about specific movies, and the other two duplicate each other and only need the [stan-lee] and the [marvel-universe] tag.

Comment: marvel universe can stand for anything and is bit ambiguous  but Marvel Cinematic Universe have a specific meaning . Read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe

Comment: I didn't realise that it was actually called that, I apologise. I thought it was just someone on this site trying to differentiate between the movies and the overall universe. Very well, I'll accept your answer, because there's no point combining the tags if one of them has a specific meaning.